# Nissa - Vital Force, does the land that becomes a creature can get destroyed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I want to ask about the +1 ability of [Nissa, Vital Force](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNissa%2c%20Vital%20Force%5d).

If the creature (that was the untapped land) dies from combat damage or any other effects, is the land removed from battlefield afterwards? Usually I´d say yes, but the card explicitly says `It´s still a land`.

If it is removed, then can I bring the land back with the -3 ability?

Thank you.

Comment: You can also destroy lands that aren't creatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be destroyed by having sufficient damage on it. Also, [Terror](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerror%5d) ('Destroy target creature.') will work just fine.

The text:

> 'It is still a land'

signifies that it can still tap for mana and that it is affected by spells and abilities that target lands (ie: 'Destroy target land').

Once it is removed from the battlefield, the card becomes just a land card. Since lands are permanents, you can target them with Nissa's -3 ability.

Comment: Dammit then my opponent was right. Guess I have to apologize to him. Thank you.